# TFS what is the keep checkout option

Tags: tfs

In TFS there is an option in Visual Studio to "Keep Items checked out when checking in" what is the purpose of giving such an option?

I am trying to build a reporting tool to find out the list of files that are checked out, so in the case the user has set the above option would my report be accurate, since the developer can always claim that "Hey, all my changes are checked in"

How do i reflect those kind of checkout in my report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this feature when part of what I'm working on is needed by another developer, but I haven't actually finished the whole task.

Your report would still be accurate, as it's a true reflection of the system - the code really is checked out, and the developer is probably still working on the file. The only way you can truly know if all changes are checked in is by comparing the current version from source control with each developer's locally checked out copy, which isn't going to be feasible for reporting purposes, and is probably of limited value.

Answer (score 2):

In a modern CI environment it's very common to commit changes and simply keep changing the very same modules.
On the other hand, once a milestone is reached, the developer will simply commit the changes & start working on something else.
So, I think it's very natural for TFS to provide with this configurable flag.
Another major feature in the TFS ecosystem is gated-checkin: is this mode the commit is shelved, built & committed once all that has succeeded. If it weren't for this option, the developer would have to stand still & wait until the process has finished.
I would disagree with a developer stating "Hey, all my changes are checked in": our principle in the team is that everything that is checked out is being developed, anything else is/should be either shelved or committed.
You could consider a rule that all pending changes of each developer get shelved at the end of the working day. I am personally against any such measures, but would surely examine them as a option if my devs wouldn't adapt to the principle.
If you would agree to the above, your second question would become rather obsolete: In my opinion there aren't several 'kinds' of checkouts.

Comment: Agree totally. One questions, How does the dev commit to a shelveset is that something configurable? looks like this method avoids having build breaks or atleast gives more control over it.

Comment: You can find the "Pending Changes" window by navigating to "View">"Other Windows">"Pending Changes". There you will see all your checked out source files. "Check In" & "Shelve" buttons stand there side by side.